# How to put a required field?

Tags: html, required

Why is the required attribute dont work?

```
<div class="Field">
  <div class="name">{name}</div>
  <div class="type"><input type="text" name="a_name" value="{$a_name}" required></div>
</div>
<div class="ProfileButtonSave">
  <div class="submitMiddleBlue" onclick="ButtonClick()">{#languageKey286#}</div>
</div>
<script>
  }

  function ButtonClick() {
    jQuery('#EditProfile').submit();
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "dont work" - what exactly are you trying, what happens, and what did you expect to happen instead?

Answer (score 0):

Submitting the form using JavaScript bypasses the validation check.

Replace the `<div>` with a `<button>` (which has the extra benefits of making the page more accessible to screen reader and keyboard users) and remove the (now redundant) JS.

Comment: hello i am starter in this programing world
i repleced div tith button

 <div class="ProfileButtonSave">
<button class="submitMiddleBlue" onclick="ButtonClick()">{#languageKey286#}</button>

and nothing happend

i still dont get the required field

Comment: <button type="button" onclick="ButtonClick()">{#languageKey286#}</button>

did not solve the issue

Comment: @VladoPranjic — A regular submit button not a button with `type="button"`.  **And remove the JS** entirely.